# MySQL: retrieve id from other table

Tags: mysql

A simple MySQL question:

I have 2 tables called "Interfaces" and "Switch".

**The table "Switch":**

```
create table switch (
      name varchar(15), 
      swversion varchar(15), 
      bootversion varchar(15), 
      serialnumber varchar(30), 
      rootbridge varchar(10), 
      address varchar(20), 
      switch_id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      PRIMARY KEY(switch_id));
```

**The table "Interfaces":**

```
create table interfaces (
      port varchar(15), 
      type varchar(20), 
      duplex varchar(15), 
      speed varchar(5), 
      neg varchar(20), 
      flowctrl varchar(5), 
      linkstat varchar(5), 
      backpres varchar(20), 
      mdixmode varchar(5), 
      switch_id int(11), 
      PRIMARY KEY(port));
```

I want to get the switch_id from the table "Switch" into the switch_id in the table "Interfaces".

In this example: every switch with the port: "Switch2_..." should get the Switch_id: 1", "Switch5_..." should get Switch_id: 2, and so on.

http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/4470/switchid.png

The switch_id from "Interfaces" should be updated automatically with the switch_id from the table "Switch"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be ambiguous - you have two switches with the name "switch2": id values 1 and 4. So do you want id 1 or id 4 to be associated with the switch named "switch2"?

A better approach will be for you to change how you populate the tables. First create a switch, find out its id using last_insert_id() and then use that value as the switch_id when you add all the records for the interfaces. Then you don't have to go back and fix things later - you get the right values in the right places from the start.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried using the last_insert_id but it simply gives "0" as output. I think this happens because I don't insert my data in the database but I simply load it in from a textfile. Any ideas for this?
As for the two switches with the name "switch2", that was just some testdata I inserted. In a real case scenario here there would never be two switches with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
INSERT INTO Interfaces(switch_id)
SELECT switch_id
FROM Switch WHERE......
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html